# Elasticsearch aggregation with completion

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have documents with nested array tags with type term.completion:

```
            {
             "url": "xxx",
             "imageUrl": "yyy",
             "tags": [
                "icon",
                "gold",
                "golden",
                "3d",
                "shadow",
                "bend" ]
            }
```

I do completion query by field tags.completion:

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "autocomplete_by_tags": {
      "prefix": "gold",
      "completion": {
        "field": "tags.completion"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and get good result started with prefix 'gold':

```
 "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "gold",
                        ...
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "gold ball",
                        ...
                    },
```

**Question:**

How i can do aggregation (facets) on completion result ("gold", "gold ball")?

I try this query but return by any tags in document not equal completion resutl ("gold", "gold ball"):

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "autocomplete_by_tags": {
            "prefix": "gold",
            "completion": {
                "field": "tags.completion"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "autocomplete_tag_count": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tags"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
},



"buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "clip art",
                    "doc_count": 11017
                },
                {
                    "key": "media",
                    "doc_count": 10809
                },
                {
                    "key": "public domain",
                    "doc_count": 10657
                },
```

Excepted result:

```
"buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "gold",
                    "doc_count": 111
                },
                {
                    "key": "gold ball",
                    "doc_count": 222
                },
```